# Where to find django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin class source code

Tags: python, django

I was interested in reading source code of `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin` and have found it in django github repo in [straightforward corresponding file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/admin.py).

But it inherits `django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin` which couldn't be located this simple because `django.contrib.admin` has `__init__.py` file which internally uses [autodiscover_modules](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/module_loading.py) utility and I completely misunderstand how it works.

**The question is**: How could I guess in which file is source code of `django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin` situated?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin

Comment: How do you know he is using that django 1.11 version?

Comment: The `__init__` file has an import from `options` file: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py#L10 You could also use the `__module__` attribute of the class. `inspect.getsourcefile(ModelAdmin)` is another option.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, yes, you are right ``inspect.getsourcefile`` is what I needed. Thanks a lot! (if you converted comment to answer I would accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a shell (with ipython installed) with the virtualenv activated

```
./manage.py shell
```

And import the module

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin
```

Then just type

```
ModelAdmin??
```

This can be applied to any python module

Without ipython

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin

import inspect

inspect.getfile(ModelAdmin)
```

Comment: What if they are not using IPython?

Comment: I added an alternative, but, let's be honest, just install ipython.

Comment: @lapinkoira, to be honest, it's absolutely no need to clutter work environment with ipython

Comment: Well, unless you are reading production source code which is riskier than installing ipython, I would recommend you just use it to learn about python at a dev environment. You can use it for many things besides the ?? which normal python shell is lacking. It has a very intuite sintax, where, as you can see, at normal python you must import inspect and search for the right function.

Comment: If so I would recommend install `django-extensions` and use `shell_plus`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin` class source code in the `options.py` module.